# Are url encoding implementations standardised across languages?

Tags: c#, url, url-encoding

I'm building a web service in c#, and I want to retrieve strings passed as url parameters. I'm intending on decoding these strings using c#'s HttpUtility.UrlDecode method. Obviously this service will work fine for clients who have encoded the parameters using the corresponding urlencode method in c#, but will it work for clients using url encode methods of other programming languages?

I'm aware there is a standard defined for url encoding, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Current_standard , but do (most common) langauges conform to it, and interact happily with each other?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you experiencing problems with this?

Comment: "Other languages" such as Java, or "other languages" such as Chinese?

Comment: I meant other programming languages. I've not experienced any issues, but wanted to be sure it was the correct approach before deploying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what standards are meant for. To allow interoperability between systems built with different platforms/languages. So unless there's a bug in the specific implementation or library that you are using there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed, but wanted to check.

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems the c#  method HttpUtility.UrlEncode is not standards compliant, but Uri.EscapeDataString is.